# Bash: local array shadowing parameter ends up empty

Tags: bash

I have just noticed (by accident) that with `bash`, if I use a local array inside a function to hold an array passed as a parameter and give that local array the same name as the global parameter passed to the function, the local array ends up empty. This sound a little convoluted so here is an example:

```
foo() {
    declare -a bar=("${!1}")
    echo "${bar[@]}"
}

bar=(1 2 3)
foo bar[@]
```

On my system, Linux running `GNU bash 4.4.23` this prints a newline. However both the following variants output `1 2 3`:

```
foo() {
    echo "${bar[@]}"
}

bar=(1 2 3)
foo bar[@]
```

As well as:

```
foo() {
    declare -a foobar=("${!1}")
    echo "${foobar[@]}"
}

bar=(1 2 3)
foo bar[@]
```

I would like to know why this happens, I would guess this has something to do with how bash performs name resolution but I'm not sure at all. Note that I'm not looking for an alternative way to do the same thing I'd just like an explanation.

EDIT: the third snipped previously contained `echo "${bar[@]}"` but should have read `echo "${foobar[@]}"`.

Comment: None of the working alternatives given in  this question have output that depends on any kind of successful indirect expansion *at all* -- both of them refer directly to the global variable `bar` straight from the `echo` line. (The former doesn't set up any locals at all; the latter sets up a local, but doesn't use it in any way).

Comment: Yeah my bad, the second example should echo `foobar`, I'll fix that.

Comment: (Incidentally, the issue you bring up here also applies to namevars, and are why it's considered preferable for someone defining a namevar in a function to prefix it for namespacing purposes: `declare -n myfunc_foo=$1` will work even if the array named in `$1` is `foo`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you declare a local, it starts out empty.
- Indirect variable references use names that are in-scope at lookup time -- meaning, they'll match an empty local before a non-empty global with the same name.

...which is also to say that `foo bar[@]` isn't in any respect passing the contents of `"${bar[@]}"` as it exists in the current scope, but is just passing the string `bar[@]` (if you're lucky; if a file named `bar@` exists in the current directory, it could be expanded as a glob). And when an indirect lookup is done on `bar[@]` in the context of a function where `bar` is a local... well, there's your problem.

---

So, a more informative example of a working alternative is this:

```
foo() {
    declare -a local_bar=("${!1}")
    echo "${local_bar[@]}"
}

bar=(1 2 3)
foo 'bar[@]'
```

...where your local has a different name (`local_bar`), so the global isn't shadowed by an empty local.